# Firebase priority and child_moved

Tags: firebase

I pushed an item with server time stamp priority. After that I got a child_added message for just pushed item with priority set to local time stamp.

I was expecting that child_moved should be called when locally cached pushed item priority is synchronized with server, but it's never happened.

What is the right way to be notified about server item timestamp priority sync completed.  What is the point of child_moved in that case?

Comment: Feel like sharing the code that reproduces the behavior you're describing? It may depend on the order in which the operations are sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you described was a bug in a previous version of the Firebase client, but was fixed in v2.0.0, released November 4th, 2014. Check out the https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/changelog.html.

Now, when you have a listener for `child_moved` events, and invoke `setPriority(Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP)` on one of the children, you'll receive *two* `child_moved` events: the first for the initial client-only change in priority, and a second after the server has populated the server version and your client has seen the latest value.